# calling controller and passing value through onlick listener

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<?php 
    foreach($fetch_file as $row)
    {   
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . base64_decode($row->file_perm_desc) . '</td>';
        echo '<td style = "text-align:center;">' . date_format((date_create($row->date_entry)),"M d, Y")  . '</td>';
        echo '<td class = "text-center"><a class="btn btn-info" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "editid" class = "openid" value = ' . $row->file_perm_id . '>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></td>';
        echo '<td class = "text-center"><a class="btn btn-warning" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "editid" class = "unpublishid" value = ' . $row->file_perm_id . '>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></td>';
        echo '<td class = "text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "editid" class = "deleteid" value = ' . $row->file_perm_id . '>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></td>';
        echo '<td class = "text-center"><a class="btn btn-success" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "editid" class = "downloadid" value = ' . $row->file_perm_id . '>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

     }      
?>  


  $('.btn-info').click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).find('.openid').val();
        window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url();?>ClientCont/List_Files");


    });
```

I have this onlick listener from the value above on the user click the button it should go to the controller but I dont know how can I call controller and pass the value from id. this is in codeigniter framework hope somebody can help thanks

Comment: `.find('.publishid')` I don't see any elements with a matching `class` but I do see **unpublishid** Also you don't seem to ever close your anchor tags.... `</a>`

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$('.btn-info').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('.openid').val();
  if (id) 
  {
     window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('ClientCont/List_Files/');?>" + id;
  }

});
```

*Your controller's `List_Files` method should be like this :*

```
public function List_Files($id)
{  
   /*echo passed id from the js here like this */

   echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

1. The html code is wrong. Closing anchor tag ("`</a>`") is missing. Fix the html as below

   ```
      '<td class = "text-center"><a class="btn btn-info" ><input type = "hidden" name = "editid" class = "openid" value = ' . $row->file_perm_id . '><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open">**</a>**</td>'
   ```
2. Try the below javascript code.

   $('.btn-info').click(function() {

   ```
     var id = $(this).find('input').val();
     var url = "<?php echo base_url();>ClientCont/List_Files?id="+id;
     window.location.replace(url);
   ```

   });